# A faster way to loop through a dataframe and filter it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, scipy, vectorization

I have two datasets: One is a dataframe of all parcels that have sold in the past few years(Primary) in a county the other is a dataframe of every parcel in that county(Secondary). I have created a distance matrix between the two.

After creating this distance matrix I then loop through row by row of the Primary Dataframe and filter it to only return parcels from the Secondary Dataframe that are within a certain distance(Rangez).

I then take this filtered dataframe and return some information about the closest 5 parcels by matching the index(ID column) to the Secondary DataFrame.

```
for i in range(len(Dmatrix)):
neighbors = Dmatrix.iloc[i].loc[(Dmatrix.iloc[i]<=rangez) == True & 
                                (Dmatrix.iloc[i]>0.001)].sort_values(axis = 0).reset_index()
try:
    append = [primaryLatLong['Index'][i],
               neighbors['Index'][0],
              '{:0.4f}'.format(neighbors[list(neighbors.columns)[1]][0])+' Miles',
              '${:,}'.format(int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][0]]['AssessedValue'])),
              int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][0]]['YearHomeBuilt']),
              neighbors['Index'][1],
              '{:0.4f}'.format(neighbors[list(neighbors.columns)[1]][1])+' Miles',
              '${:,}'.format(int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][1]]['AssessedValue'])),
              int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][1]]['YearHomeBuilt']),
              neighbors['Index'][2],
              '{:0.4f}'.format(neighbors[list(neighbors.columns)[1]][2])+' Miles',
              '${:,}'.format(int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][2]]['AssessedValue'])),
              int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][2]]['YearHomeBuilt']),
              neighbors['Index'][3],
              '{:0.4f}'.format(neighbors[list(neighbors.columns)[1]][3])+' Miles',
              '${:,}'.format(int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][3]]['AssessedValue'])),
              int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][3]]['YearHomeBuilt']),
               neighbors['Index'][4],
              '{:0.4f}'.format(neighbors[list(neighbors.columns)[1]][4])+' Miles',
              '${:,}'.format(int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][4]]['AssessedValue'])),
              int(SecondayLatLong.loc[SecondayLatLong['Index'] == neighbors['Index'][4]]['YearHomeBuilt'])
              ]
except:
    append = [i,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0]
append = pd.Series(append,index = threeclosest.columns)
```

is there a faster way to perform this iteration? The Secondary Dataframe will contain 100's of thousands of row and the primary Dataframe can contain 10's of thousands - at its peak the runtime can take several hours.

TIA.

Comment: Unfortunately without data sample, it will be hard to get help. Please setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My first thought is to use GeoPandas and spatial join.